# How to extend a navbar background, while keeping the elements in the center?

Tags: html, css

I want the blue of the navbar to extend across the screen, while the About, Updates, and Who am I? to stay in the middle? I want the background to remain a background so that it will change if I resize anything. I am fine with a different centering method, if that works better.

```css
.centered {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#navbar {
    background: #0099CC;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 51px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#navbar ul, #navbar li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
#navbar ul {
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
#navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    display:flex;
    line-height: 51px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #0099CC;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

#navbar label {
    display: none;
    line-height: 51px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px
}
```

```html
    <div class="centered">
    <nav id='navbar'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Updates</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Who am I?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 100% width to #navbar to extend across the screen and change display & width properties for #navbar ul, like this

```
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}
```